# Will there be a Microsoft Edge (Chromium) 'webview' control for MacOS?

Tags: webview, microsoft-edge

Microsoft Edge (Chromium) is in [Beta on MacOS](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2069148&platform=Mac&Consent=0&channel=Stable).  Will there be a Microsoft Edge (Chromium) '[webview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/hosting/webview2)' control for MacOS?  I suppose this is dependent on having support for .NET Core.  Currently the support is limited to C++.

Is [this same link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/hosting/webview2), it says "In the future, we plan to support WebView2 on .NET.", I would assume this means .NET Core?  Does anyone know what the plan is?

Comment: This has been assigned an issue at: https://github.com/MicrosoftEdge/WebView2Feedback/issues/1314

Comment: Thank you @Jwosty

Answer (score 3):

According to the comments in [this Issue](https://github.com/MicrosoftEdge/WebView2Feedback/issues/645) there is a plan to support Linux and MacOS, but probably only post 2021.

It is stated, that support for these platforms is on their Roadmap, though.

Answer (score 1):

At present, we are not available with any information on whether there will a webview control for the MS Edge Chromium browser for MAC OS or not. We also don't have any information about it's future plan.

I suggest you wait for the official announcement from Microsoft about webview control for MAC OS.